# Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Tags: android, unity3d

Я использую Unity 2020, и когда я пытаюсь скомпилировать свой проект, я получаю следующие ошибки:

1)

```
 > Configure project :launcher
 WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
 It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow 
 you to disable R8.
```

2. 

```
  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
 > Failed to query the value of task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' property 
 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
> Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, 
property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class 
org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, 

 H:\FinalPluginProjectTest\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\release\out))) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@545c8bb4) before task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported
```

3. 

```
 CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\bin\java.exe -classpath "H:\gradle-7.0\lib\gradle-launcher- 
 7.0.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

 stderr[
 Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
 > Failed to query the value of task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' property 
 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
 > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory,       
 property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class 
 org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, 
        
  H:\FinalPluginProjectTest\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\release\out))) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@545c8bb4) before task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported
```

кто-нибудь знает, в чем проблема? Если нужно добавить информацию, пишите! Пожалуйста, помогите, если сможете, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в версии такого компонента как Gradle: я зашел во вкладку Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools, и там нажал на галочку Gradle installed with Unity

```
              хорошего всем дня  =)
```